# Impossible to save category with more that 1000 products

Tags: products-management, category, php

This is a known issue caused by PHP 5.3.9 and `max_input_vars` that by default it is set to 1000.

The solution 2 proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851064/why-does-magento-keep-only-the-first-1000-products-in-a-category-after-saving-t) it is the best in my opinion but doesn't work: for some strange reason it limit the category to 527 products.

For that reason I'm posting this question with related corrected answer

Comment: Maybe the limit is not 527. Maybe you reach the `max_post_size`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in the question this issue has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851064/why-does-magento-keep-only-the-first-1000-products-in-a-category-after-saving-t) but the answer was not working fine for me.

I'm adding here a complete working solution (`method 2`).

this is the code that is working fine for me:

```
            $cat_products_split = explode('&', $data['category_products']);
            foreach ($cat_products_split as $row) {
                $arr = explode('=', $row);
                if (count($arr) == 2) {
                    $products[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
                }
            }
```

**- HERE THE STEPS TO FIX IT -**

**1. Creation of a new module**

let create a module `CategoryFix` in local.

Here the `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MYNAMESPACE_CategoryFix>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MYNAMESPACE_CategoryFix>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <!--FOR THE USE OF OUR CONTROLLER BEFORE THE CORE ONES -->
                        <categoryfix before="Mage_Adminhtml">MYNAMESPACE_CategoryFix_Adminhtml</categoryfix>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**2. Override the category controller ( `saveAction()`)**

Controller file: `/MYNAMESPACE/CategoryFix/Adminhtml/Catalog/CategoryController`

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php';
class MYNAMESPACE_CategoryFix_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController
{  
    /**
     * Category save
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
     // 1. COPY HERE THE CODE FROM THE ORIGINAL SAVEACTION() METHOD
     // 2. COMMENT THIS LINE: `parse_str($data['category_products'], $products);`
     // USE THE CODE REPORTED ABOVE  
    }
 }
```

Comment: /MYNAMESPACE/CategoryFix/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/CategoryController.php worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I added this to the .htaccess file in Magento root:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 100000
</IfModule>
```

After setting that Magento allowed me to have more than 1001 products in one category.

Comment: take care your solution make your server more vulnerable to DDoS attack