# 1000 Category Limit not working with 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

Since updating Magento to 1.8 I have noticed the fix I was using for the 1000 Category save "bug" (quotes as Magento stupidly don't consider it a bug) isn't working anymore.

I was using the one from here: [Impossible to save category with more that 1000 products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/impossible-to-save-category-with-more-that-1000-products)

Has anyone got any idea why not, I have compared the saveAction between versions but can't find what would be breaking the fix?

Comment: Why just raise the `max_input_vars` limit?

Comment: Feel uneasy raising it as isn't there any security concerns about having a too large value, wasn't that why it was lowered in the first place?

Comment: There are, but if you need it higher, then raise it. The reason it was introduced was a hash collision vulnerability: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/171-PHP-Vulnerability-May-Halt-Millions-of-Servers.html

Answer (score 3):

After quite a few hours of playing the linked answer I referred to in my previous question I found it had a little error in it. I had to change the location of the category controller file to within a `controllers` folder:

```
/app/code/local/NAMESPACE/CategoryFix/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog
```

Complete working code

https://github.com/medialam/magento-category-fix

Comment: As to why it was working for me in 1.7 I had changed the file in the core when I first started with magento before I learnt what a bad idea that was! The upgrade to 1.8 wiped over it

Comment: you sir are a legend. Thanks for packaging this up for easy use. Works perfectly. Pretty major bug for Magento to have ongoing and not fixed as yet. I'm sure it's in the list to fix though.

Comment: @Blair no, they don't consider it a bug!