# How to extend magento product category limit from 1000 to 5000 in magento by php.ini

Tags: magento-1.8, php, category

I need to extend max input var in magento for increasing category product limit. On 1000 product my category is not working with more than 1000 product...

I need to extend `max_input_vars` in Magento without touching `php.ini` file...

In `index.php` I have put this:

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
```

is it good for increasing `max_input_vars` for Magento?

I'm using VPS and on that it is restricted to touch or change `php.ini`

So I need to put my code in `index.php`. I just want to know if that is fine.

Or any good solution please.

Answer (score 3):

instead of changing the `max_input_vars` I think it's better to fix the issue in Magento.
This way you won't depend on the environment settings.
[You can find here a complete solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6320/146). It involves rewriting the `saveAction` of the product admin controller and instead of using `parse_str` (the function that depends on `max_input_vars`) you just parse "manually" the data sent through post.