# Magento 2 : Category page not listing all the products

Tags: magento2

I am working on a Magento 2 store , which have more than 30000 products in it. And out of all categories , 1-2 categories have more than 12000 products.

But for the category which have more than 12000 products , on the front end I can see only 10000 products.

Can anyone please help , What should be the issue?

Comment: Did you check inventory and visibility level?

Comment: what is the value of 'max_input_vars' in your phpinfo ?

Comment: @triyugi  the value for  'max_input_vars'  is 16384

Comment: @DineshSaini Also check  'max_post_size'  and if it will not work then look into http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/impossible-to-save-category-with-more-that-1000-products/6320#6320

Comment: @triyugi 'post_max_size' is 8M and regarding reference link , i don't have any issue to add products , in my admin side its already have more than 13000 products in a category, but on front end only 10000 are visible

Comment: perform reindexing and then check again

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today after testing the default importer performance with 100k products into a single category and noticing the frontend only showed 10k.

After looking through the files and speaking to #magento on IRC I come across the issue. `Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_results.xml` contains 3 `<size>...</size>` attributes in the XML which are all set to 10000 by default.

I've detailed how to create a very simple module to overwrite this .xml file here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/225c498e81565fd6d6a3de670c008593

Basically you register your module with a custom *Vendor* name but with the *Module* name of "CatalogSearch" and then add the .xml file into the correct structure. I then just changed the values from 10000 (10k) to 100000 (100k).

Depending on your version of Magento, stuff may change so I would recommend copying the .xml each time you set this up instead of using the one from my gist. The path to the file (as of 2.0.5) is `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml`

*Note: I think you only need to change the XML section for 'catalog_view_container' but I changed all 3 just in-case the search results ever need to show 10k+ items.*

Comment: thanks for your answer , actually i was getting that issue with magento 2.0.2 and after upgrade to 2.0.5 its working without an changes in search_request.xml file , but still one up for you